# How to load jpg file from server to be used as a variable in a function?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an image stored in my server as follows:

"C:\xampp\htdocs\Users\101\arrow.jpg"

How can I extract it from my server and send the file as a variable in a php file? The variable will be used in a function to upload the file through an api.

It must be able to do this:

```
is_file($variable) = true;
```

Comment: Please, provide more information ?

Comment: What type of information do you need?

Comment: What did u try already .. First u need to understant that img is not send .. u send path to image so u can get the path to image and send it.

Comment: how to do then it then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_get_contents` to get the file. You can then base64 encode this file and send it along to the API as string.

```
$base64image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\Users\101\arrow.jpg'));
```

Comment: I get filesize(): stat fail

Comment: @joseph.w, you can not copy and paste the same comment to different solutions! Please check it!

Comment: @joseph.w Can you show your full code? It's difficult to tell you what's going wrong when we can't see where you are using the filesize() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the image to Base64 and assign it to a PHP variable:

```
$val = base64_encode("C:\xampp\htdocs\Users\101\arrow.jpg");
```

Comment: I get filesize(): stat fail